# how to add and delete a sub document in MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb, document

For example, suppose I have this document {name : "John", Address : { Street : "Main St", City : "Houston", State : "TX"}, email : "John@gmail.com"}

If I want to delete the subdoc "Street" in the above document, what should I do?
If I want to add a sub doc "Zip".

> db.collection.remove()

by the way, is there any wildcard character in db.collection.find() to match a field name ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `$set` and `$unset`.  You would use it like so:

```
db.collection.update({name: "John"}, {$unset: {"address.street": ""}, $set: {"address.zip": 94105}})
```

There is not a wildcard field name matcher in MongoDB.  I don't anticipate one in the future.